# hibernate lower not working

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to do a case-insensitive search in `hibernate` so am using the `lower()` function on the database field and java `String.toLowerCase()` on the parameter as so:

```
String query = "from LdapData where lower(ntid) = ? ";
Query stmt = session.createQuery(query);
stmt.setString(0, ntid.toLowerCase());
result = (List<LdapData>)stmt.list();
```

result is returning an empty list when a query in SQL Developer shows there is one there, but in upper case. Seems like its not being converted to lower.

Can anyone see anything wrong with this?

Comment: It's a String ntid

Comment: and in the database it's NTID NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String query = "from LdapData where lower(ntid) like ? ";
```

Comment: Why would it make a difference?

Comment: like will be case insensitive

Comment: ... and `=` is not?

Comment: you are right = is case insensitive also. I just check it

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `Locale` to `lowercase()` method like :

```
stmt.setString(0, ntid.toLowerCase(new Locale("tr-TR")));
```

(replace `tr-TR` with your locale id http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javase7locales-334809.html)