# Oracle 11g,12c LOWER TURKISH character problem

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, lowercase

sql:

```
select LOWER('I') FROM DUAL

Result:
LOWER('I')
i

select nls_lower('I',nls_sort='xturkish') from dual;

Result:
nls_lower('I')
ı
```

i want use the `lower` function of the `hibernate`, how can I cast that to Oracle's `nls_lower` ?

Comment: If `nls_lower` works why not use it?

Comment: how to cast hibernate lower to nls_lower ?

Comment: have a look at Arif's answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39925599/hibernate-lower-not-working

Answer (score 1):

`nls_lower` is part of [Locale-Dependent SQL Functions with Optional NLS Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96529/ch7.htm)

> All SQL functions whose behavior depends on globalization support conventions allow NLS parameters to be specified. These functions are:
>
> - TO_CHAR
> - TO_DATE
> - TO_NUMBER
> - NLS_UPPER
> - **NLS_LOWER**
> - NLS_INITCAP
> - NLSSORT

So use it instead `lower` for Turkish support